# Kubuntu UEFI Dual Boot with Windows 7 failed at installing Grub-efi

Tags: grub2, windows-7, kubuntu, uefi

I want to install Kubuntu 13.04 together with Windows 7 in UEFI Mode. I installed Windows 7 first, which created the EFI boot partition.

When it come to installing Kubuntu, the installation failed when trying to install Grub-efi on sda with the error that grub-efi install to /target/ failed.

There is a simliar thread with the same problem but on 12.04:

[Why 12.04 Fails to install grub-efi to /target/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260297/12-04-2-failed-to-install-grub-efi-to-target)

..and the solution was to use 12.10. But I'm using a newer version of (k)ubuntu.

Any Solutions here are highly welcome.

Update:

It also doesn't work with just kubuntu on the disk,  so it's definitely not a dual boot issue.

Solved:

I used 12.10 and the installation succeded without any problem except that grub didn't add Windows. Fix that with boot-repair.

I found a Kubuntu Bug entry which says, that it's probably a kernel Bug in 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

If the installation has mostly finished, but just failed on the GRUB installation, I have two suggestions:

- Try [Boot-Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which should set up GRUB for you.
- Try the USB flash drive or CD-R version of [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) If that gets Linux booted, you can then install the Debian package version, which with any luck will install without error to the hard disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I isntalled now with 12.10 and it succeded at first try. See my addition aboth.