# Ubuntu 12.04 --- grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, grub-efi

I have HP Pavillion 14-n009tu laptop (i-5, 4GB) with Windows-8 OS installed on it.
I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 as a dual boot OS on Windows8.
I have disabled fast boot and secure boot options also.
I am facing following error while installing ubuntu 12.04:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/. Without GRUB boot loader,
the installed system will not boot
```

I have created three partitions:

1. 38GB-ext4- Root mounted
2. 08GB-ext4- `/home`
3. 10GB Swap area

Please guide me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: after installing ubuntu try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Could you also paste in the full partition table. As these may be in extended partitions, which can cause issues occasionally. If you run boot repair as suggested this information is in the paste link which you are given at the end.

Comment: I also had this problem on a Linux Mint 18.1 MATE install. The solution for me was to disable the internet connection while installing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Answer (score 3):

Hey Ramji Had the exact same problem.
What fixed my problem was that i went through the steps again and made sure I was connected to the Internet the second time. 
go through the process again (don't partition again because the hard drive is still partitioned ) but this time chose the option to format the partitions so that you erase the information that was loaded before the installation failed.
look at the comments here 
[Why 12.04 Fails to install grub-efi to /target/?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260297/12-04-2-failed-to-install-grub-efi-to-target)
if you are still having problems follow this instructions
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by creating a 200MB FAT32 partition in the beginning of the disk with the flags **boot** and **esp**. Creating a partition with this configuration was suggested by boot-repair tool after I got the error you mentioned and I tried to fix it using such tool.

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: This is the correct solution! More info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_System_Partition

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. If you are installing using a pendrive, just modify the filename `grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.9~ubuntu12.04.4+1.99-21ubuntu3.10_amd.deb` in directory `/pool/main/g/grub2-signed/` by adding `64` at the end before `.deb`. It works 100%.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1633913

Comment: Not the case for 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue in Linux Mint 16 by running the following command before starting the install:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

It's probably caused by installing both 32- and 64-bit versions of all packages, in case only one of them exists (or maybe to support heterogeneous clusters that have both 32-bit and 64-bit CPUs). In the case of `grub-efi-amd64` (which is part of `grub-efi-amd64-signed`), both versions exist, but they declare conflicts with each other so that they can't both be installed on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem while installing Ubuntu 16.04 as well as while installing Mint.

The following steps fixed my problem:

1. Install Ubuntu/Mint whichever you want (after the installation or in-between, you'll get this error).
2. Start o. with live boot.
3. Install boot repair.
4. Follow steps in that.

That's it. Restart your PC and remember to remove the bootable medium you used.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the "Fast Boot" and "secure Boot" options in Boot Options menu. Select Legacy Boot. Restart the installation process. Create a boot partition >1MB during installation. This solved the issue for me in UBUNTU 16.04 LTS installation.
Partitions created:
/boot       - 2048 MB
swap        - 10000 MB
/           - 50000 MB
/home       - 100000 MB

Marked remaining to be unused.