# Unable To Install Grub/EFI For Lubuntu

Tags: grub2, system-installation, lubuntu, uefi

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 13.10 X86-64 on my laptop, but it's not working. Lubuntu itself installs fine, but at then end when it tries to install grub it fails and doesn't write anything to the UEFI partition. I'm attempting to install Lubuntu onto an SDHC card and specified that the internal hard drive's UEFI partition should be used. I've received the same result twice.

Details:

Internal 1TB sata hard drive running Windows 8. It's partitioned in GPT and has 4 partitions. 1=UEFI 2=Windows 8 3=Data 4=Data

SDHC 32gb for Lubuntu 13.10. It's partition in GPT and has 2 partitions. 1=UEFI (but I've deleted this so currently it's unformatted empty space), 2=Lubuntu

Secure Boot is disabled otherwise the Lubuntu disc is rejected as insecure, which is weird since secure boot support was added to Ubuntu back in 12.04.2-ish.

EDIT:

I believe the error message was "Failed to install grub-efi to /target/"

Comment: According to "http://askubuntu.com/questions/260297/12-04-2-failed-to-install-grub-efi-to-target?rq=1" having no internet connection could be the cause? In which case it's a serious bug. I'll give that a try.

Comment: yes that was the problem, of course now even though it installs I just get grub rescue, and even boot-repair fails to fix the problem...grrr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it was the internet connection. I connected to my wifi network and the installation completes with grub successfully installed [though grub only boots into rescue mode].