# How to Resolve this grub-efi-ia32 error in Asus T100 of 16.04?

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation, uefi

I receive this message when installing Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 on Asus T100:

> The 'grub-efi-ia32' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

Hardware: Asus Transformer T100
Ubuntu: 14.04, 16.04

Comment: Your question is almost identical to one or more that have already been posted. The following answer that gives instructions how to install Grub should work: http://askubuntu.com/a/774537/40581 (see also http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/40581). Rod Smith explains in his answer what could have caused the issue, if you give the installation another try it should complete without issues. If not then https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUbiquity to provide logs would be the next step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [12.04.2 Failed to install grub-efi to /target/](http://askubuntu.com/questions/260297/12-04-2-failed-to-install-grub-efi-to-target)

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.